# Should I check on NaN parameters of a coordinate object?

Tags: javascript, properties

Using an `{ x: 0, y: 0 }` object(and objects that have `x` and `y` properties) for geometrical calculations. Thinking on a checking function.
The question: do I need to check if `x` and `y` are numbers?
E.g. which variant is better:

```
function isCoordObj ( obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( 'x' ) 
      && obj.hasOwnProperty( 'y' ) 
      && !isNaN( obj.x ) 
      && !isNaN( obj.y ) ) {
          return true;
    }
    throw new Error( 'not a Coord Object' );
}
```

or this one is enough:

```
function isCoordObj ( obj ) {
    if ( obj.hasOwnProperty( 'x' ) 
      && obj.hasOwnProperty( 'y' ) ) {
          return true;
    }
    throw new Error( 'not a Coord Object' );
}
```

Comment: Totally up to you. Though `isNaN` won't help much if `obj.x = "5"` and you do something like `obj.x + 10`. `isNaN` converts the argument to a number first.

Comment: If you want, you can use `typeof o === 'number'`.

Comment: It depends on how *isCoordObj* is created. If it's entirely under your control and you want values to be certain types, make sure they are the correct Type when assigned. Otherwise, you likely need to check Type and perhaps range of values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If x and y were never assigned to NaN, you do not need to do NaN check. On the contrary to this, if it were quite probable that x and y assigned to NaN and it cause critical problem to an application, you have to do NaN check. I think that it's a decision of problem.